# Converting CSV file data points to line feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, csv, polyline-creation, length

I have added a CSV file data points into QGIS. Then I opened properties and tried to convert points inside the plot as single line (used option > properties > symbology >  marker > geometry generator > Line string).

But, I can't see any data in my plot after selecting this option. Is there any other way to convert points to line?

[image: Data points within districts of India]

Comment: The symbology has nothing to do with feature conversion. `v.to.lines` from the toolbox is what you want.

Comment: There is also a possibility from SAGA GIS: [Convert points to line(s)](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.3.0/shapes_lines_1.html).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you the geometry generator is not what you want, basically it's a symbology tool that allow you to use a different geometry on your feature (like representing your point by a polygon buffer for exemple). If you are creative you may be able to create a line with it but the more commun way to convert ordered point to line is by using a geoprocessing tool.

Go to processing toolbox and look for either :

- "Point to path" tool in QGIS>vector creation
- "v.to.lines" in GRASS>Vector
- "Convert point to line(s)" in SAGA>Vector line tools

each of these tool will create a new line layer based on your point

Comment: By the way, do you know the difference between these three algorithms and which one is the quickest/efficient?

Comment: @Taras No I have no idea if these use different method or not or if one is better than another

Comment: Since your question was successfully answered, please accept the answer by clicking the tick.

Comment: And perhaps indicate which function you used to get the result.