# Calculating distance between points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, distance, csv, tracking

I have a CSV file with a bird track and multiple points with exact coordinates as well as date and time. My CSV files are divided by days.

Here is an image of attribute table:
[image]

How can I calculate the total distance the bird has traveled?

Comment: Convert your `points to lines` and calculate the `$length`.

Comment: ... and avoid coordinates system like WGS 84 (EPSG: 4326) or pseudo-mercator (EPSG: 3857) for compute distances, project your data first, distances in degrees don't work very well ...

Comment: Check this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314022/convert-csv-file-data-points-to-line-feature-in-qgis